# Enviar e-mail desde mutt usando Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, email

Llevo un rato trabajando con el cliente de correo Mutt e intentando implementarlo en mi script de Python pero algo me está dando error. Primero deciros que lo tengo configurado bien y que puedo enviar e-mails desde la consola con el comando:

```
echo "Mensaje" |  mutt -s "Asunto" correo@dominio.com
```

Pero estoy tratando de implementar esto en un script Python que necesito que envie por correo una foto y no soy capaz, el codigo es este:

```
       fecha = time.strftime("%d%m%Y-%H%M%S")  # En esta variable se guarda la fecha actual y la hora para renombrar la foto guardada
       camera.capture('/home/pi/Desktop/RaspAlarm/Fotos/{}.jpg'.format(fecha))
       print("Capturando foto")
       time.sleep(2)
       print("Foto guardada")
       print("Enviando foto")
       os.system('echo "La alarma ha sido activada {}" .format(fecha) |  mutt -s "Alguien a abierto la puerta" smma_225@hotmail.com -a /home/pi/Desktop/RaspAlarm/Fotos/{}.jpg .format(fecha)')
       print("Foto enviada con exito")
```

El programa no me da ningún error pero no manda el correo. No se si es que no se puede usar mutt dentro de Python, o si hay alguna otra manera de enviar un correo. He visto que hay librerias smtp especificas pero he visto más sencillo usar mutt aunque no se si es posible.

Gracias de antemano!

Comment: ¿Que versión de Python estas usando? 2.7, 3.5, 3.6...

Comment: Estoy con Python 3

Comment: Creo que el error está en intentar poner una variable dentro del os.system. {}" .format(fecha) por que si quito eso y escribo algo normal si que envia el correo perfectamente. Pero la cosa es que necesito enviar la fecha y hora actual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estas usando de forma inadecuada `format`. A `os.system` le pasas una cadena con la orden, `format` debes aplicarlo a la cadena como método. Ahora mismo lo que le pasas a `os.system` es el siguiente comando **literalmente**:

```
'echo "La alarma ha sido activada {}" .format(fecha) |  mutt -s "Alguien a abierto la puerta" smma_225@hotmail.com -a /home/pi/Desktop/RaspAlarm/Fotos/{}.jpg .format(fecha)'
```

`format` no esta siendo usado como un método, es parte de la cadena al estar englobado dentro de `''`. Tu código debe ser:

```
fecha = time.strftime("%d%m%Y-%H%M%S")  # En esta variable se guarda la fecha actual y la hora para renombrar la foto guardada
camera.capture('/home/pi/Desktop/RaspAlarm/Fotos/{}.jpg'.format(fecha))
print("Capturando foto")
time.sleep(2)
print("Foto guardada")
print("Enviando foto")
os.system('echo "La alarma ha sido activada {0}" |  mutt -s "Alguien a abierto la puerta" smma_225@hotmail.com -a /home/pi/Desktop/RaspAlarm/Fotos/{0}.jpg'.format(fecha))
print("Foto enviada con exito")
```

Para aclarar un poco simplificando el ejemplo:

- Tu haces algo como:

  ```
  >>> fecha = "12/10/2016"
  >>> c = 'echo "{}".format(fecha)'
         #^                      #^ 
  >>> print(c)
  echo "{}".format(fecha)
  ```
- Cuando debe ser:

  ```
  >>> fecha = "12/10/2016"
  >>> c = 'echo "{}"'.format(fecha)
         #^        #^
  >>> print(c)
  echo "12/10/2016"
  ```

Comment: Perfecto. Marcada como solución, es como tu me has dicho. Estaba poniendo mal el .format